# how can I use the to_image_src in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new in wordpress and I noticed that at my DB im saving values as 20 on a custom tag, to print it they use something like this:

```
print_custom_field('my_logo:to_image_src')
```

And basically, it prints the image URL.

Reading this I noticed it says accepts the ID of an image and returs the URL

I have on my meta_key and meta_value fields the following

```
meta_key = my_logo
meta_value = 20
```

Still, not sure how to make it work?

I bring the meta_key and meta_value value with a query. So, basically, I dont know how can I come from there to get the path (as I have it on a previous template).

Thanks

Comment: So is the image stored in the Media Library?

Comment: yes, I uploaded to the media library but using a plugin "custom fields" but on the name of the input that is "my logo" it only stores "20" and I have no idea why.

Comment: Is it the Plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)?

Comment: No, is one called "Custom Content Types" If I create a custom content type named "custom" for example and I add the custom-page.php , then I can do this print_custom_field('my_logo:to_image_src') and it prints the URL of the image. The problem is that now I want to incluide it at other page, so I did a query to the DB and I bring back the values, but I realized that the images values are stored in that way...

Comment: it returns 20, but if I do this mysite.com?attachment_id=20 it takes me to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code where you want the images to appear:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_logo' ), 'full'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_logo' )) ?>" />
```

This will get the full-sized image for you using the ID that is returned from the my_logo key.

Comment: thanks, I was writting the same answer as well, but you wrote it first